# Why php is not uploading the file in temporary folder?

Tags: php, laravel, windows, file-permissions

I am using windows, and it seem like `fopen` is working in a strange way:

`opendir('F:\folder'); // works like charm`

`fopen('F:\folder\file.txt', 'r'); // doesn't throw any error`

`dd(file_get_contents('F:\folder\file.txt')); // returns file content`

`dd(substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('F:\folder')), -4)); // 0777`

But when trying to do:

`fopen('F:\folder', 'r');`

I got this error: **fopen(F:\folder): failed to open stream: Permission denied**

Do you have any idea why this might happen? Thank's in advance!

**Update 1**

The code fails on first line in this function:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php`

```
public function putFileAs($path, $file, $name, $options = [])
{
    $stream = fopen(is_string($file) ? $file : $file->getRealPath(), 'r');

    // Next, we will format the path of the file and store the file using a stream since
    // they provide better performance than alternatives. Once we write the file this
    // stream will get closed automatically by us so the developer doesn't have to.
    $result = $this->put(
        $path = trim($path.'/'.$name, '/'), $stream, $options
    );

    if (is_resource($stream)) {
        fclose($stream);
    }

    return $result ? $path : false;
}
```

**Update 2 (How `putFileAs` is used?):**

`$file; // Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`

```
$this->storage = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk($disk);

$this->storage->putFileAs($this->getDirectory(), $file, $this->name)
```

**Update 3 (content of `$file` variable)**

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1331
  -test: false
  -originalName: "avatar.jpg"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -error: 1
  #hashName: null
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath: "F:\folder1\folder2\folder3\public"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

Notice: Windows Process Monitor shows an result of **IS DIRECTORY** on **CreateFile** action when executing `fopen()`

***Update 4***

The problem appears to be in file upload (the file is not being uploaded to temp folder)

I run two versions of PHP

1. php74 - the problem persists

file is not being uploaded in temp folder in order to be available in script, that causes this:

`realPath: "F:\folder1\folder2\folder3\public"`

respectively, this causes the error when trying to save file on the disk

2. php8 - everything working well

Now I think I should rephrase the question: **Why the PHP might not be able to upload the file in the temp folder?**

Comment: `fopen` is for files, not folders. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to save a file, the code fails in laravel framework file ```vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php``` on line 290

Comment: @aynber I've edited the question, the code fails on first line in function putFileAs

Comment: As aynber said, you cant use `fopen` for folder.  The error is clear enough that you are using it on a folder.

Comment: Since this is a core Laravel file, don't change it. How are you using `putFileAs`?

Comment: @aynber i've updated the question again, but I think the error should be more related to windows permission, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, it's because, as we said, $file is apparently a directory instead of a file name. What is the contents of `$file` before that last line?

Comment: @aynber I added $file variable content to question

Comment: You're missing a lot of information in your UploadFile object. path, filename, base name, pathname, and extension are all empty, realPath should have the file name, not just the folder. So there's something wrong with the file upload and the way it's being detected.

Comment: @aynber you're right, I have done some testing and the file is not uploading in the temporary folder in order to be available during the script execution, I think this is the problem I need to solve